# BuddyPress Group creation date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, buddypress

I want to display the creation date of a group with the date format `j. F Y`

For that, I tried the function `bp_group_date_created()`. Unfortunately I get the wrong format (10 days ago). The function also didn't accept any other format.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a soultion:

Copied the original function in the functions.php and changed it like this:

```
function bp_get_group_date_created_ch( $group = false ) {
    global $groups_template;

    if ( empty( $group ) )
        $group =& $groups_template->group;

    return apply_filters( 'bp_get_group_date_created', strtotime( $group->date_created ) );
}
```

In the template I used this:

```
<?php $timestamp=bp_get_group_date_created_ch(); echo gmdate("j.m.Y", $timestamp); ?>
```